# How can i change color of this minicart-wrapper counter.qty with _theme.less

Tags: magento-2.1, less-css

i want to know how can i change the color of this .minicart-wrapper .action.showcart .counter.qty when i search on my browser i know the name of css class are .minicart-wrapper .action.showcart .counter.qty but on my _theme.less i don't know how can i access that with @name to change brackground color.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `@active__color` and that will change it, however it will also affect other elements that use this variable.

To change just the counter element, you can copy `/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Checkout/web/css/source/module/_minicart.less` to `{theme_dir}/Magento_Checkout/web/css/source/module/_minicart.less` and change the value in there (line 179).